# Why is hardlink and softlink required ?

Tags: linux, unix

What is the use of creating a Hardlink and a softlink ?  In what kind of scenarios do we create them ?

Comment: Are you asking why we need a distinction between them, or why we need any of them at all?

Comment: I need to know why we need them at all ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been discussed in length on sites that are more appropriate for this question.

[When would creating a hard link be useful?](https://superuser.com/questions/288286/when-would-creating-a-hard-link-be-useful/288287#288287)

[What is the difference between a soft (symbolic) link and a hard link?](https://serverfault.com/questions/10543/what-is-the-difference-between-a-soft-symbolic-link-and-a-hard-link)